# When I save a openpyxl it changes the colour of all the rows / columns/ text

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Essentially I am trying to make a little app for the people I work with to automatically fill out our weekly timesheet's. It will ask you your name, which days you worked, how long for(inc overtime) and populate this data into a pre-made excel spreadsheet made by the various companies we work for.

So to start I am just learning how to edit cells with the input from the user.

My issue during my quick tests - in a blank excel document when I run wb.save(test.xlsx) it will update it with my changes but it makes all the colours go funky for some reason (image attached)

[image: Table issues]

Im not quite sure why it's doing this - I tried googling but all I could find was info on how to change the colour of the rows not anything relating to my problem. It's probably something really obvious but I thought I would ask anyway.

Really appreciate any help!

Edit - attached code -

```
# Timesheet Bot v1.0
import os
import sys
import openpyxl

from openpyxl.styles import colors
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color
from openpyxl import Workbook

path = ('/Users/namehere/Desktop/Test')
os.chdir(path)
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet 1']


print ('')
print ('')
print ('')
print ('')
print ('Hello and Welcome to Timesheet Bot 1.0 - I am Roger')
print ('I will sort out your Timesheet(s). Lets get started!')
print ('')
print ('\033[91m' + "I now will ask you a few questions about your work week." + '\033[0m')
print ('')
print ('')
print ('')
name = str(input('What is your full name? '))
sheet['C4'] = name

weekending = str(input('What is the week ending date ? (Sunday and must be DD/MM/YY) '))
sheet['C5'] = weekending

start = int(input('What was the start time for the week?'))
sheet['C7'] = start
sheet['C8'] = start
sheet['C8'] = start
sheet['C9'] = start
sheet['C10'] = start
sheet['C11'] = start



end = int(input('What was the end time for the week?'))
sheet['D7'] = end
sheet['D8'] = end
sheet['D8'] = end
sheet['D9'] = end
sheet['D10'] = end
sheet['D11'] = end


wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you've already found a workaround by now, but I just ran into the very same problem and found the underlying issue.

This happens specifically to files that are created with Apple Numbers. If you use any colors in Numbers, the color information gets saved into a global color palette. Unfortunately the palette information gets lost when saving the data to a new file in openpyxl, so your spreadsheet software will fall back to the default palette.

I've opened a [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/pull-requests/340/add-support-for-writing-custom-color/diff) that should fix the issue.